# How do I bind the enabled binding of a button to whether or not an NSArrayController has a selection?

Tags: cocoa, button, state, cocoa-bindings

I want to bind the enabled state of an NSButton to whether or not an NSArrayController has any selected items.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another option is to bind to `selectedObjects.@count`

Comment: That should be selectedObjects.@count I believe

Comment: Currently, Xcode accepts (and breaks the above into) `selectedObjects` in Controller Key and `@count` in Model Key Path

Answer (score 18):

Generally speaking, binding the `enabled` binding to the `canRemove` property of the array controller should give you what you want. After all, you can only remove an object if there's one selected.

Comment: At a much later date than written, this does not work.

Comment: This works for me configuring the binding in IB in Xcode 8.2.1. Making sure that only the "Controller Key" is filled out with "canAdd" or "canRemove", there is no model key path or value transformer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer for IB:
[image]

If you need to setup the OR relationship with other NSArrayController (or other value), there is the section Enabled 2 , and so on. So, in my case, i have:

[image]